# Removing outliers from 3-way ANOVA data using boxplot.stats()$out

Tags: r, boxplot, anova, outliers

I am trying to remove outliers from 3 way anova data which includes three independent variables (IV1, IV2 & IV3) each having 3 levels and one dependent variable (DV).DV is continuous numerical variable. I concatenated all the three categorical variables as IV4 and made one more concatenation of IV4 and DV as AV in my data frame(v). Then, I identified outliers using boxplot.stats()$out and concatenated it with respective group of categorical variable it corresponded to. Later, I removed the identified outliers from the original data frame using which() function.

```
Levels of Independent Variables:
IV1 - a,d,g
IV2 - b,e,h
IV3 - c,f,i
```

```
#identifying outliers at each combination of levels in IV4
boxplot(DV~IV4,data=v)

#filtering outliers by defining new data frames
vabc <- vt[v$IV1=="a" & v$IV2=="b" & v$IV3=="c", ]
oabc <- paste("a b c",boxplot(DV~IV4,data=vabc)$out,sep = " ")
vdef <- vt[v$IV1=="d" & v$IV2=="e" & v$IV3=="f", ]
odef <- paste("d e f",boxplot(DV~IV4,data=vdef)$out,sep = " ")
vghi <- vt[v$IV1=="g" & v$IV2=="h" & vt$IV3=="i", ]
oghi <- paste("g h i",boxplot(DV~IV4,data=vghi)$out,sep = " ")

#removing outliers
v <- v[-which(v$AV%in%c(oabc,odef,oghi)), ]
```

I was able to detect outliers and remove them with this method but it gets tedious when there are more outliers. Hence, I am looking for a quick way to do this.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But are you sure you should be doing this? Once you drop one set of outliers you might just be creating new outliers. And what exactly is an "outlier" really depends on your particular data and domain. I strongly suggest you consult a statistician for alternative ways to analyze your data.

Comment: I strongly endorse @MrFlick's recommendation that you consult a statistician.  By removing outliers, you are fitting your data to your model.  You should be fitting your model to your data.  The [Anscombe datasets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) are, amongst other things, a classic demonstration of why this is important.